# Is there an R function for transforming entire df into lower?

Tags: r, uppercase, stringr, lowercase, stringi

I'm setting up a data table & expected to transform all data to be in lower-case, thought it would look neat. How can I do that ?

Comment: Please you need to provide more info, what you have tried or where are you stuck or what issue you are facing. thanks

Answer (score 4):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(TestData)[, lapply(.SD, tolower)]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
TestData %>%
     mutate_if(is.character, tolower)
```

Comment: Thanks. Data table name is TestData. Is the code below is correct ?
TestData[, lapply(.SD, tolower)]

Comment: @Mr.KT  Yes, assuming it is a data.table

Comment: I tried but throwing up an error
Error in tolower(`Address Line 1`) : 
  invalid input 'Dolní 3137/100' in 'utf8towcs'

Comment: @Mr.KT  I think that is a encoding issue, you may have to check the settings

Comment: Error msg: Cannot find symbol TestData

Comment: @M  You only said the dataset name is `TestData`

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I will give it a try & let you know

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative that can also be combined with `mutate` from `dplyr`:

```
purrr::map(Filter(is.character,my_data),~tolower(.x))
```

We can also achieve the same using a combination of `dplyr` and `purrr` as suggested by 
@Shinobi_Atobe

```
my_data %>% 
keep(is.character) %>% 
map(~tolower(.x))
```

Comment: probably just semantics, but I'd have gone with `my_data %>% keep(is.character) %>% map(~tolower(.x))`

Comment: @Shinobi_Atobe I'll add that to reflect integration with `dplyr`. Thanks!

Comment: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘purrr’

Comment: @Shinobi_Atobe Error in my_data %>% keep(is.character) %>% map(~tolower(.x)) : 
  could not find function "%>%"

Comment: @Mr.KT If you don't have these packages, please run `install.packages(c("purrr","dplyr"))`;`library(purrr)`;`library(dplyr)` first.